# first try to create archive to test , getting Code Sign error: The identity 'iPhone Developer' doesn't match any valid

Tags: iphone

I followed [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/YourFirstAppStoreSubmission/TestYourApponManyDevicesandiOSVersions/TestYourApponManyDevicesandiOSVersions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011375-CH5-SW1) tutorial.

Just to try and test my ever first app in my iphone , but when creating the app in archive I get the error :

```
Check dependencies

The identity 'iPhone Developer' doesn't match any valid, non-expired certificate/private key pair in your keychains
```

in the Scheme I selected the iOS Device .
What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **Navigator** click on your project, then choose your **Target** and in **Build Settings** look for **Code Signing**. 
In **Code Singing Identity** you can set your developer certificate/provisioning profile which will be use to sign you archive.

As fas as I'm concerned most used configuration is:

> Debug: iPhone Developer: your_name from iOS Team Provisioning Profile
>   *

or

> iPhone Developer: your_name from com.company.appBundle

(it depeneds how to generated Provisioning Profiles in developer.apple.com)
and for

> Release: iPhone Distribution from com.company.appBundle

especially when you are using iCloud or In-App Purchases (even if you are testing your app).

P.S

When deploying to TestFlight you can sign your app with Ad Hoc profile.
When depolying to iPad you are still using "iPhone Distribution Prov. Profile".

Comment: the creating profiles via xcode still not working ( apple say it will be ready this week ) i only created Ad Hoc profile in there web site
is this aproblem ?

Comment: I think there is no problem, because you can download Ad Hoc, when you enter record for this Prov. Profile you will have "download" button. I don't think you need active Internet connection to sign app so it should be okay.

Comment: i wish there was more easy step by step for dummy's guide , easier them 
the one in apple site